# Hot water radiator bleeder valve replacement

Tags: valve, radiator

Does the valve to the radiator need to be turned off before replacing a bleeder valve?

In the photo my finger is at the part that leaked. Thanks for any advice.

I had the bleeder valve replaced, but the valve then leaked causing significant water damage to my basement.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Most hot water radiators have two connections - flow and return - and only one valve so closing it does not isolate the radiator or reduce pressure in it.

So typically, no, turning off the valve does not accomplish anything.

If you have a bunch of faulty/failed bleeder valves you should drain the whole system and replace them all. If you do not, there isn't much of a lesson to be learned here. You should typically never have to replace one again in your own home if they are all working now.